# Object null refrence Model is null

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am getting issue while binding the data to view from controller.
Object null refrence Model is null.
I have a Main Class inside that i have defined all sub classes which i need to expose to view.

```
public class MarketDataDetails
    {
        public List<Region> GetRegion { get; set; }        
        public List<Product> GetRegionProduct { get; set; }
        public List<Market> GetRegionMarket { get; set; }
        public List<Segment> GetMarketSegments { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RegionList { get; set; }
    }
```

In Controller :

```
public ActionResult MarketData()
{            
 marketData.RegionList =_marketDataService.GetRegions().Select(o=> new SelectListItem {Value = o.RegionId.ToString(),Text = o.Name}).ToList();    
return View("MarketData");

 }
```

When i debug my controller i can see all data populated in MarketData()
In View :

```
@model Model.MarketDataDetails

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MarketData";
}
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetRegion.Count; i++)
    {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.GetRegion[i].RegionId, Model.RegionList)
    }
```

I get Object refrence null error in view .Model is null.
Please help.

Comment: Is this when you initially render the view, of just of you return the view in the POST method (e.g. if `ModelState` is not valid)?

Comment: Initially rendering the view then

Comment: JTMon's answer is correct (I didn't spot the quotes in `return View("MarketData");` - it should be just `return View(marketData);` )

Comment: This works. But @for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetRegion.Count; i++) { @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.GetRegion[i].RegionId, Model.RegionList) } it is creating five dropdown as datacount is 5. How to resolve that ? –

Comment: You are asking the view to draw as many drop downs as the items returned by the GetRegion method. If you want just the one dropdownList then just the remove the for  loop from around the DropDownlistFor helper.

Comment: If i remove forloop  @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.GetRegion[i].RegionId, Model.RegionList) i am not able to get RegionId Property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the model to the view.

```
{            
    marketData.RegionList =_marketDataService.GetRegions().Select(o=> new SelectListItem {Value = o.RegionId.ToString(),Text = o.Name}).ToList();    
    return View("MarketData", marketData); //Add the model to the return statement
 }
```

Comment: Could be just `return View(marketData);` since the method is named `MarketData`

Comment: This works. But @for (int i = 0; i < Model.GetRegion.Count; i++)
    {
    @Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.GetRegion[i].RegionId, Model.RegionList)
    } it is creating five dropdown as datacount is 5. How to resolve that ?